# How to pull information from a Json

Tags: python, json

I was wondering how to use the requests library to pull the text from a field in a Json? I wouldn't need beautiful soup for that right?

Comment: If you have already have the json structure, check out the json module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your response is indeed a json format, you can simply use **requests** `.json()` to access the fields, example like this:

```
import requests

url = 'http://time.jsontest.com/'

r = requests.get(url)
# use .json() for json response data
r.json()
{u'date': u'03-28-2015',
 u'milliseconds_since_epoch': 1427574682933,
 u'time': u'08:31:22 PM'}

# to access the field
r.json()['date']
u'03-28-2015'
```

This will automatically parse the json response into Python's dictionary:

```
type(r.json())
dict
```

You can read more about [response.json](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json) here.

Alternatively just use Python's `json` module:

```
import json

d = json.loads(r.content)

print d['date']
03-28-2015

type(d)
dict
```

Comment: Hmmm my Json is:{
 "response": {
  "steamid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "success": 1
 }
}How can I take out the Steamid?

Comment: @Marorin, just like you do in Python dictionary, that is: `r.json()['response']['steamid']`

Comment: @Marorin, no worries we all do occassionally :-)

Answer (score 0):

What version of Python are you using ? From 2.6 onwards you can do this:

```
import json

json_data=open(file_directory).read()

data = json.loads(json_data)
print(data)
```

Comment: I think the auther asked the other way around, so `json.loads(some_json)`

Comment: Changed the code snippet, but upvoted Anzel's answer as it is more detailed and likely more useful as well..